# didSelectItemAt not working from SCLAlertView

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uialertview

I am using SCLAlertView to create custom alert view. My alert view contains one text field and collection view of coloured cells 
[image: custom alert view]

Problem is that UICollectionView's didSelectItemAt method is not working. I think problem is because it is like subview. But I can't fix it. 
I have one collection view at UIViewController and that method is working. Here's my code

```
    var collectionViewAlert: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 1, left: 1, bottom: 1, right: 1)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 25, height: 25)

        collectionViewAlert = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 18, y: 10, width: 250, height: 25), collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionViewAlert.dataSource = self
        collectionViewAlert.delegate = self
        collectionViewAlert.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollCell")
        collectionViewAlert.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    }

    @IBAction func addCategory(_ sender: Any) {
        let alertView = SCLAlertView()
        alertView.addTextField("Enter category name")

        let subview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:216,height:70))
        subview.addSubview(self.collectionViewAlert)
        alertView.customSubview = subview
        alertView.showEdit("Choose color", subTitle: "This alert view has buttons")



    }



    let reuseIdentifier = "cell" // also enter this string as the cell identifier in the storyboard
    var colors = [UIColor.red, UIColor.yellow, UIColor.green, UIColor.blue, UIColor.cyan]

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.colors.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        // get a reference to our storyboard cell
        if (collectionView == self.collectionViewAlert) {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
            cell.backgroundColor = self.colors[indexPath.item]
            return cell
        }
        else {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath)

            cell.backgroundColor = self.colors[indexPath.item]// make cell more visible in our example project
            return cell
        }

    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
    }

}
```

More screens here: [screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2MK6.jpg)

**EDIT:**

I still not found answer how to solve this problem. I think problem is subview interaction, because delegate method `cellForItemAt` is invoked on alert show. Someone know how to figure this out? screen from view hierarchy [image: view]
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you please defined `didSelectItemAt` method is not working.

Comment: Is your collection view inside a view with `isUserInteractionEnabled` set to `false`?

Comment: @Sulthan collectionViewAlert isUserInteractionEnable is set to true, also subview interacion to true but still not working

Comment: Could you check with `Debug View Hierarchy` that nothing is blocking the selection?

Comment: Looking into the code of `SCLAlertView`, they use a tap recognizer to hide keyboard when tapped outside the text input. There could be a collision with your collection view selection. Try to create `SCLAlertView` with `disableTapGesture` in appearance set to `true`.

Comment: @Sulthan Thank you very much!!! Finally after 4 hours this fixed my problem. Also thanks to other suggestions :)

Comment: @bzadm Okey, I have posted that as an answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have looked into `SCLAlertView` [code](https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift/blob/master/SCLAlertView/SCLAlertView.swift#L305). It seems it uses a tap recognizer for dismissing the keyboard.

Tap recognizer can conflict with the tap recognizer used by collection view.

To disable the recognizer in `SCLAlertView` you can use an appearance object:

```
let appearance = SCLAlertView.SCLAppearance(
    disableTapGesture: true
)
let alertView = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add extension for CollectionView delegate:

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate
{
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
    }

}
```

If you have added any UIImageView or UILabel inside UICollectionViewCell make sure you have enabled UserIntraction, because for both UIImageView or UILabel default as false.

setUserIntraction for both UIImageView or UILabel as TRUE.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add collectionview delegate in protocol section. And be sure that you have make outlets of your object.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to update like:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
}
```

And then in viewDidLoad:

```
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.dataSource = self
collectionView.reloadData()
```

And make sure that your objects are properly connected.

Comment: Thanks for quick response but it's not working. I am not sure if you get what my problem is. Here's full code https://pastebin.com/saKznz2a and some more screens to understand. http://imgur.com/a/VZhT9 Thanks

Comment: Have you make proper outlets of it....And also check in your design that the collection view is not hiding behind of any other view